# In R how to make a string of fields in to a SQL join

Tags: sql, r

In R given a string like "fld1,fld2" how can I get something like "b.fld1=v.fld1 and b.fld2=v.fld2" for a SQL query.  The string may have up to 10 distinct elements.  This is for trying to build a join on the fly.  b and v are the aliases for two tables.  There willo only be two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String interpolation with `stringr::str_glue` is a convenient way of achieving this:

```r
library(stringr)
sql_join <- function(columns, table1, table2) {
  columns_vec <- str_split(columns, ",")[[1]]
  str_glue("{table1}.{columns_vec} = {table2}.{columns_vec}") %>%
    str_c(collapse = " AND ")
}

sql_join("fld1,fld2", "b", "v")
#> [1] "b.fld1 = v.fld1 AND b.fld2 = v.fld2"
sql_join("fld1,fld2,fld3,fld4", "foo", "bar")
#> [1] "foo.fld1 = bar.fld1 AND foo.fld2 = bar.fld2 AND foo.fld3 = bar.fld3 AND foo.fld4 = bar.fld4"
```

Comment: Will look at that.  the sql_join function is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Express this in one line of code by replacing each field with the comparison expression and then replacing each comma with `and`.  No packages are used.

```
s <- "fld1,fld2"  # input

gsub(",", " and ", gsub("([^,]*)", "b.\\1 = v.\\1", s))
## [1] "v.fld1 = b.fld1 and v.fld2 = b.fld2"
```

Note that some data base systems such as SQLite and PostgreSQL support `using(fld1,fld2)` in place of `on` in which case the input string `s` could be directly inserted into the SQL string without having to massage it.

For example,

```
library(sqldf)

names(BOD) <- c("fld1", "fld2")  # input

# as above
cond <- gsub(",", " and ", gsub("([^,]*)", "b.\\1 = v.\\1", s))
out1 <- fn$sqldf("select b.* from BOD b join BOD v on $cond")

# via 'using' -- this uses the input 's' directly
out2 <- fn$sqldf("select b.* from BOD b join BOD v using($s)")

identical(out1, out2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Added example and discussion of `using` .